# Reverse geocoding in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I'm attempting to write a simple method that's fed `CLLocationDegrees` and returns a `CLPlacemark`. Looking at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation#), it seems like a simple task.

Below is what I've dumped into a playground:

```
import CoreLocation
// this is necessary for async code in a playground
import PlaygroundSupport 
// this is necessary for async code in a playground
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

func geocode(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) -> CLPlacemark? {
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    var placemark: CLPlacemark?
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("something went horribly wrong")
        }
        if let placemarks = placemarks {
            placemark = placemarks.first
        }
    }
    return placemark
}
let myPlacemark = geocode(latitude: 37.3318, longitude: 122.0312)
```

---

As it stands, my method is returning nil. I'm not sure where my error lies, but I rest assured it's something starlingly stupid on my part. Thank you for reading.

Comment: geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation is async you would need a completion handler

Comment: Thank you. I'll see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I'm trying to pass coordinates that are stored as Doubles in Core Data.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

CLGeocoder methods are asynchronous. What you would need a completion handler:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

---

```
func geocode(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, completion: @escaping (_ placemark: [CLPlacemark]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)  {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)) { placemark, error in
        guard let placemark = placemark, error == nil else {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        }
        completion(placemark, nil)
    }
}
```

or simply:

```
func geocode(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, completion: @escaping (_ placemark: [CLPlacemark]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void)  {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude), completionHandler: completion)
}
```

or extending CLLocation:

```
extension CLLocation {
    func geocode(completion: @escaping (_ placemark: [CLPlacemark]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(self, completionHandler: completion)
    }
}
```

---

To format your placemark as a mailing address you can use Contacts framework `CNPostalAddressFormatter`:

```
import Contacts

extension Formatter {
    static let mailingAddress: CNPostalAddressFormatter = {
        let formatter = CNPostalAddressFormatter()
        formatter.style = .mailingAddress
        return formatter
    }()
}

extension CLPlacemark {
    var mailingAddress: String? {
        postalAddress?.mailingAddress
    }
}

extension CNPostalAddress {
    var mailingAddress: String {
        Formatter.mailingAddress.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

---

> **placemark**
>
> Contains an array of CLPlacemark objects. For most geocoding requests,
> this array should contain only one entry. However, forward-geocoding
> requests may return multiple placemark objects in situations where the
> specified address could not be resolved to a single location. If the
> request was canceled or there was an error in obtaining the placemark
> information, this parameter is nil.

For more information about the CLPlacemark properties you can check this [CLPlacemark](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clplacemark)

---

Usage:

```
let location = CLLocation(latitude: -22.963451, longitude: -43.198242)
location.geocode { placemark, error in
    if let error = error as? CLError {
        print("CLError:", error)
        return
    } else if let placemark = placemark?.first {
        // you should always update your UI in the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //  update UI here
            print("name:", placemark.name ?? "unknown")
            
            print("address1:", placemark.thoroughfare ?? "unknown")
            print("address2:", placemark.subThoroughfare ?? "unknown")
            print("neighborhood:", placemark.subLocality ?? "unknown")
            print("city:", placemark.locality ?? "unknown")
            
            print("state:", placemark.administrativeArea ?? "unknown")
            print("subAdministrativeArea:", placemark.subAdministrativeArea ?? "unknown")
            print("zip code:", placemark.postalCode ?? "unknown")
            print("country:", placemark.country ?? "unknown", terminator: "\n\n")
            
            print("isoCountryCode:", placemark.isoCountryCode ?? "unknown")
            print("region identifier:", placemark.region?.identifier ?? "unknown")
    
            print("timezone:", placemark.timeZone ?? "unknown", terminator:"\n\n")

            // Mailind Address
            print(placemark.mailingAddress ?? "unknown")
        }
    }
}
```

---

This will print

> name: Morro da Saudade
> address1: Rua Casuarina
> address2: 597
> neighborhood: Lagoa
> city: Rio de Janeiro
> state: RJ
> subAdministrativeArea: unknown
> zip code: 22011-040
> country: Brazil

> isoCountryCode: BR
> region identifier: <-22.96345100,-43.19824200> radius 141.83
> timezone: America/Sao_Paulo (current)

> Rua Casuarina, 597
> Lagoa
> Rio de Janeiro RJ
> 22011-040
> Brazil

Comment: Thank you! This gets the job done. I don't think I'm going to be able to declare a `let` constant like this, given it's async code. I'll refactor this `let myPlacemark = geocode(latitude: 37.3318, longitude: 122.0312)
` with something else.

Comment: You need to use it inside the closure

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: HI, How to get the complete state name?, not in ISO code format.

Comment: @LeoDabus, how can we get the complete state name,  is it possible?

Comment: @KishanBhatiya I am not sure but I don’t think you can at least when  using this framework

Answer (score -3):

There are so many questions dealing with 'reverseGeocodeLocation' on Stack Overflow, I've seen so many of them. I'm using Swift 4.2 and I thought my 'reverseGeocodeLocation' requests might be timing out. Well, this is NOT the case, when starting to move with an iPhone the 'didUpdateLocations' cycles need to mature. It can take two or more cycles before 'reverseGeocodeLocation' returns placemarks.

I wrote a simple app that uses 'reverseGeocodeLocation' until 'placemarks' are returned after repeated 'didUpdateLocations' cycles. This is my own home grown 'SampleCode'. I learned a lot from using the app, it might help others understand how reverse geocode requests work in the real world.

Please give your comments on possible improvements. This code is freely given and freely taken.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBAction func RefreshLocationButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.requestingPlacemark = true
        self.placemarkData = nil
        //^Make another Placemark Request
        self.requestCounter = 0
        self.RequestCounterLabel.text = ""
        self.LocationLabel.text = ""
        self.PlacemarkLabel.text = ""}
    @IBOutlet weak var LocationCounterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var RequestCounterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LocationLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var PlacemarkLabel: UILabel!
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var placemarkData: CLPlacemark!
    var placemarkString: String!
    var printPlacemarkData: Bool!
    var didUpdateLocationsCounter: Int = 0
    var requestCounter: Int = 0
    var requestingPlacemark: Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        //locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.RequestCounterLabel.text = ""
        self.LocationLabel.text = ""
        self.PlacemarkLabel.text = ""}}
func printPlacemarks() {
    if printPlacemarkData {
        self.placemarkString = "Placemark Data:"
        self.placemarkString = buildPlacemarkString(item: 1)
        self.placemarkString = buildPlacemarkString(item: 2)
        self.placemarkString = buildPlacemarkString(item: 3)
        self.placemarkString = buildPlacemarkString(item: 4)
        self.placemarkString = buildPlacemarkString(item: 5)
        self.placemarkString = buildPlacemarkString(item: 6)
        self.placemarkString = buildPlacemarkString(item: 7)
        self.placemarkString = buildPlacemarkString(item: 8)
        self.placemarkString = buildPlacemarkString(item: 9)
        self.placemarkString = buildPlacemarkString(item: 10)
        self.PlacemarkLabel.text = self.placemarkString
        self.printPlacemarkData = false}}
func buildPlacemarkString(item: Int) -> String {
    var elementText: String!
    var newString: String!
        switch item {
        case 1: elementText = "name: " + self.placemarkData.name!
        case 2: elementText = "subThoroughfare: " + self.placemarkData.subThoroughfare!
        case 3: elementText = "thoroughfare: " + self.placemarkData.thoroughfare!
        case 4: elementText = "postalCode: " + self.placemarkData.postalCode!
        case 5: elementText = "subLocality: " + self.placemarkData.subLocality!
        case 6: elementText = "locality: " + self.placemarkData.locality!
        case 7: elementText = "subAdministrativeArea: " + self.placemarkData.subAdministrativeArea!
        case 8: elementText = "administrativeArea: " + self.placemarkData.administrativeArea!
        case 9: elementText = "country: " + self.placemarkData.country!
        case 10: elementText = "isoCountryCode: " + self.placemarkData.isoCountryCode!
        default: print("Error: incorrect item number!")}
        newString = self.placemarkString + "\n" + elementText
    return newString
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //location prints one time and 'didUpdateLocations' is stopped:
    self.didUpdateLocationsCounter = self.didUpdateLocationsCounter + 1
    let labelString = String(describing: self.didUpdateLocationsCounter)
    self.LocationCounterLabel.text = "Location Update Counter: " + labelString
    if self.placemarkData == nil {
        //location variable:
        self.requestCounter = self.requestCounter + 1
        let textString = String(describing: self.requestCounter)
        self.RequestCounterLabel.text = "Request Counter: " + textString
        if locations.count == 0 {
            self.LocationLabel.text = "Locations: There was NONE"}
        else {
            if locations.count > 0 {
                let coordinate2D: CLLocation = locations.first!
                let location = CLLocation(latitude: coordinate2D.coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate2D.coordinate.longitude)
                let printString = String(describing: location)
                self.LocationLabel.text = "Location: " + printString
                let geocoder: CLGeocoder = CLGeocoder()
                geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        let errorString = String(describing: error?.localizedDescription)
                        print("reverse geodcode fail: \(errorString)")
                        self.LocationCounterLabel.text = ""
                        self.RequestCounterLabel.text = ""
                        self.LocationLabel.text = "Reverse Geodcode fail: \(errorString)"
                        self.PlacemarkLabel.text = ""
                        self.requestingPlacemark = false
                        return}
                    else {
                        let pm = placemarks! as [CLPlacemark]
                        //There is ALWAYS 'placemarks' Data
                        if pm.count > 0 {
                            self.placemarkData = placemarks![0]
                            self.printPlacemarkData = true
                            self.printPlacemarks()
                            self.requestingPlacemark = false}}})}
            else {
                if self.requestingPlacemark {
                    self.LocationLabel.text = "Problem: There is no 'location.first'"}}}}}}
```

And then the Storyboard UI:

[Storyboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJsaM.png)

[View Controller Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHsmg.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="MyThoroughfare" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Location Counter" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="2" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ZIg-u9-TMR">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="20" width="343" height="20.5"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.80000001190000003" green="0.80000001190000003" blue="0.80000001190000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Location Count Label" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="2" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="csF-KS-xGE">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="48" width="343" height="20.5"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.80000001190000003" green="0.80000001190000003" blue="0.80000001190000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Location String" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="8" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qOc-gk-gSp">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="76" width="343" height="20.5"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.80000001190000003" green="0.80000001190000003" blue="0.80000001190000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Placemark String" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="14" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="42A-nO-tNf">
                                <rect key="frame" x="16" y="104" width="343" height="20.5"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.80000001190000003" green="0.80000001190000003" blue="0.80000001190000003" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="HgN-oB-ds0">
                                <rect key="frame" x="121.5" y="578" width="132" height="30"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Request Placemark"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="RefreshLocationButton:" destination="BYZ-38-t0r" eventType="touchUpInside" id="izY-S5-wjg"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZIg-u9-TMR" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="6HO-kN-l1z"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="qOc-gk-gSp" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="csF-KS-xGE" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="7.5" id="6ux-dx-gJr"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="42A-nO-tNf" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="8dG-gV-Cob"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="HgN-oB-ds0" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="8bC-Xf-vdC" secondAttribute="centerX" id="A38-Nt-i3D"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="ZIg-u9-TMR" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="Bb0-YC-oov"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="csF-KS-xGE" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="FJU-ha-HkL"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="42A-nO-tNf" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="qOc-gk-gSp" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="7.5" id="SpR-XB-MLG"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="HgN-oB-ds0" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="59" id="Vr6-QE-230"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="42A-nO-tNf" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="aHo-kJ-aCb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="csF-KS-xGE" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="ZIg-u9-TMR" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="7.5" id="c63-Mq-ItW"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="csF-KS-xGE" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="dlV-Hc-8XJ"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="qOc-gk-gSp" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="16" id="m5y-Q8-jxI"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZIg-u9-TMR" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" id="sdw-WQ-Bx9"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="qOc-gk-gSp" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="16" id="woB-ig-i5v"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="LocationCounterLabel" destination="ZIg-u9-TMR" id="K4g-WT-f82"/>
                        <outlet property="LocationLabel" destination="qOc-gk-gSp" id="Cdw-bw-EWt"/>
                        <outlet property="PlacemarkLabel" destination="42A-nO-tNf" id="dMh-bw-cRE"/>
                        <outlet property="RequestCounterLabel" destination="csF-KS-xGE" id="ai6-zn-Toi"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="53.600000000000001" y="66.11694152923539"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```