# Set a global variable from within GeoCoder function Swift

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocation

I have a global variable "filterError" that is initially set to false before a switch statement. When the switch statement occurs, it will go through a dictionary, and for each key it will do a unique logic check on the value. If that value does not match certain criteria then the Boolean variable filterError will be set to true.

When the switch statement is complete, if filterErrror is false then the an action will occur like so:

```
//...switch statement...

if (filterErrror == false) {
    //do something.....
}
```

The issue I am having is with the geocoder function which is a case in the switch statement. If the switch variable key = "area" then the below is executed:

```
var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in

    guard let placemarks = placemarks,let location = placemarks.first?.location
    else { print("Error in finding location") return }
    let distanceInMeters = location.distance(from: coordinateSelf)
    print("The distance between property and user in miles is: \(distanceInMeters/1609)")
    distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters/1609
    var radius = Double()

    if searchRadius == "this area only" {
        radius = 0.49999999999
    } else {
        radius = Double(Int(searchRadius)!)
    }
    if (radius < distanceInMiles) {
        filterError = true
    }
}
```

However, the filterError is still false after the switch statement has completed because the boolean value is not being changed. How do you set filterError to true from inside the geocoder?

This is the full code:

```
for filter in self.activeFilters {
                                switch filter.key {
                                case "listingType":
                                    if(filter.value[0] != propertiesFirestore[i]["listingType"]![0]){
                                        filterError = true
                                    }
                                case "minBedsBound":
                                    if(filter.value[0] != "No min. beds") {
                                        if(filter.value[0].filter("01234567890.".contains) > propertiesFirestore[i]["bedroomCount"]![0]) {
                                            filterError = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                case "maxBedsBound":
                                    if(filter.value[0] != "No max. beds") {
                                        if(Int(filter.value[0].filter("01234567890.".contains))! < Int(propertiesFirestore[i]["bedroomCount"]![0])!) {
                                            filterError = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                case "minPriceBound":
                                    if(filter.value[0] != "No min. price") {
                                        if(Int(filter.value[0].filter("01234567890.".contains))! > Int(propertiesFirestore[i]["price"]![0])!) {
                                            filterError = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                case "maxPriceBound":
                                    if(filter.value[0] != "No max. price") {
                                        if(Int(filter.value[0].filter("01234567890.".contains))! < Int(propertiesFirestore[i]["price"]![0])!) {
                                            filterError = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                case "includeSharedOwnership":
                                    if(filter.value[0] != propertiesFirestore[i]["sharedOwnership"]![0]) {
                                        filterError = true
                                    }
                                case "includeRetirementHomes":
                                    if(filter.value[0] != propertiesFirestore[i]["retirementHome"]![0]) {
                                        filterError = true
                                    }
                                case "area":
                                    print(userlatitude)
                                    print(userlongitude)

                                    let address = "\(propertiesFirestore[i]["area"]![0]), \(propertiesFirestore[i]["postcodePrefix"]![0])"
                                    var propLat = String()
                                    var propLong = String()
                                    var distanceInMiles = Double()
                                    var searchRadius = self.activeFilters["searchRadius"]![0]
                                    let coordinateSelf = CLLocation(latitude: Double(userlatitude) as! CLLocationDegrees, longitude: Double(userlongitude) as! CLLocationDegrees)

                                    var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
                                    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
                                        guard
                                            let placemarks = placemarks,
                                            let location = placemarks.first?.location
                                            else {
                                                print("Error in finding location")
                                                return
                                        }
                                        let distanceInMeters = location.distance(from: coordinateSelf)
                                        print("The distance between property and user in miles is: \(distanceInMeters/1609)")
                                        distanceInMiles = distanceInMeters/1609
                                        var radius = Double()
                                        if searchRadius == "this area only" {
                                            radius = 0.49999999999
                                        } else {
                                            radius = Double(Int(searchRadius)!)
                                        }
                                        if (radius < distanceInMiles) {
                                            filterError = true
                                        }
                                    }
                                case "keywords":
                                    print("Filter keywords are: \(filter.value)")
                                    for j in 0..<propertiesFirestore[i]["keywords"]!.count {
                                        propertiesFirestore[i]["keywords"]![j] = propertiesFirestore[i]["keywords"]![j].lowercased()
                                    }
                                    for keyword in filter.value {
                                        if propertiesFirestore[i]["keywords"] == nil {
                                            filterError = true
                                        } else if ((propertiesFirestore[i]["keywords"]!.contains(keyword.lowercased()))) {
                                            print("found keyword")
                                        } else {
                                            filterError = true
                                        }
                                    }

                                default:
                                    print("Unknown filter: \(filter.key)")

                            }

                            }

                            if filterError == false {
                                filterProperties.append(propertiesFirestore[i])
                            } else {
                                print("FITLER CATCHOUT")
                            }
```

Comment: geocodeAddressString is an asynchronous method. You can only check filterError value after the async method finishes.

Comment: @LeoDabus Typo in your comment - *asynchronous*, not *synchronous*.

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes I am checking it after the whole switch statement is finished, after the default case etc.

Comment: After doesn't mean anything. All of your code should go inside the geocoder completion handler closure.

Comment: @LeoDabus fair enough that's a good point, outside of the switch statement?

Comment: Do you know what is a completion handler? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869394/reverse-geocoding-in-swift-4/46869540#46869540

Comment: You can also post a notification https://stackoverflow.com/a/30541063/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus I sort of know what a completion handler is but haven't been able to use one properly. Ive added the full code