# How make function of returning address, but not only getting address?

Tags: swift, mapkit, clgeocoder

I'll make function of returning address String.
But below function return empty String of "".

How make return address function?

```
    let defaultLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 35.17944, longitude: 129.07556)

    func convertToPlaceMark(_ location: CLLocation, data: Any?) -> String {
            var str: String? = ""
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) {
               places,err in 

               if err != nil {
                  print("geocoder error")
                  return
               }
               let placeMark1: CLPlacemark? = places!.last
               if placeMark1 != nil {
                    str = placeMark1?.name     // "1001 Jungang-daero\n" <--- I need function that return this value
                    print(str!)
                }
          }
         return str!
     }

     print(convertToPlaceMark(defaultLocation, data: nil)) // "\n"
```

Comment: Does `print(str!)` inside the closure print anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse geocoding in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869394/reverse-geocoding-in-swift-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, this function always return empty string, coz `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location)` take time to get address from Location and at same time your `return str!` also execute so you get empty string.

use closure to get address from location.

```
func convertToPlaceMark(_ location: CLLocation, _ handler: @escaping ((String?) -> Void)) {

       CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) {
           places,err in

           if err != nil {
               print("geocoder error")
               handler(nil)
               return
           }
           let placeMark1: CLPlacemark? = places!.last
           handler(placeMark1?.name)
       }
   }
```

**Usage**

```
convertToPlaceMark(location) { (address) in
        if let address = address {
            print(address)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thx for ur answer, But I do not need ur answer, Because ur code is same like code without handler. at all results address value do not need to insert handler parameter. not right?

Comment: if you do not use closure than you'll always get empty string or if you call function in main thread might you ui will freeze for moment.

Comment: i know ur mean... But also handler was not useful. Because i need return value function, not set function.

Comment: I think this is the right approach. @macmini you need to learn how completion handler works but also look at the accepted answer in the question that I think your question is a duplicate of