# Can't get block number from Reverse Geocoding Maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, maps, geocoding

I'm trying to get a specific detail from the google maps, I need to get the block number of a specific location, anyway I used the Reverse Geocoding method in [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869394/reverse-geocoding-in-swift-4), It worked perfectly but I can't find the block number, I tried all the fields returning in the `CLPlacemark` check image below:

[image]

maps blocks example:

[image]

is there any other geocoder for google maps, not Maps to use on iOS ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find another georcoder in Google Maps SDK, but I found a workaround to fix this issue.

I used this API :

```
let yourLat : Double = 33.0000000

let yourLong : Double = 34.0000000
```

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyAURQe5Ks6olxbd3x9_bm0Qyq-7y2GTREQ&latlng="\(yourLat,yourLong)"&sensor=false`

this call returns and a JSON request having any detail you need about the coordinates you provided.